# How to implement a tutorial with Drawer Navigation

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm not an Android ninja developer and I'd like to implement an app which has a Drawer Navigation and includes a tutorial.

Basically if you are in "My App" you should see a 5-6 steps tutorial.

The question is:

How can I implement that app? 
I'd like to know how to organize it and which components I should use. 
I'd really appreciate a step-by-step guide.

Thanks a lot.

---

This is a weird mockup of what I'm trying to implement :)

[image: weird mockup of what I'm trying to implement]

Comment: Have you tried [**the official guide**](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an activity on top of drawer and then you can simply put view pager in `Activity` for tutorial. When user will finish tutorial you can move user to `Drawer Navigation`.

So you can use following method.

Check if user is visiting application for first time then show tutorial activity then move to `Navigation Drawer`. If user is visiting application for second time or more then you can directly move user to `Navigation Drawer` and start app.

Answer (score 0):

If your tutorial is for the overall app, Jayesh's answer is right: you should put it in a separate Activity.

If the tutorial only demonstrates part of your app, i.e. only the drawer your are in, I suggest you use:

- One `MainActivity` with a `DrawerLayout`. The latest SDK tools have a real cool template for NavigationDrawer, that will save you a lot of time!
- In your `TutorialFragment`, write a layout with a `ViewPager` and the fixed bar at the bottom.
- Add pages for your tutorial to this `ViewPager`.